# Why is it an issue that Hibernate can't find a row with identifier on an update method, and why can't it find it?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm making an application for power lifters to save their personal records. I have a Lifter class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lifter")
public class Lifter implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false)
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String Name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lifter", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<LifterRecord> lifterRecords = new ArrayList<>();
```

a Personal record class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PersonalRecord", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "Id")})
public class PersonalRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Weight")
    private int weight;
    @Column(name = "Unit")
    private UNIT unit;
    @Column(name = "Exercise")
    private EXERCISE exercise;

    @Column(name = "Date")
    private Date dateOfRecord;
```

a class for the junction table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LifterRecord")
public class LifterRecord {

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("lifter_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Lifter lifter;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("record_id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private PersonalRecord personalRecord;

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonalRecord_LifterID personalRecordLifterID;
```

and a class for the composite key in the junction table

```
@Embeddable
public class PersonalRecord_LifterID implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "lifter_id", nullable = false)
    private Long lifterId;

    @Column(name = "personalrecord_id", nullable = false)
    private Long personalRecordId;
```

Now, I am trying to make some functionality to add a personal record to a lifter. I am using the DAO pattern. I call addRecordlifter, which first does the get to get the lifter I want to add the record to, and then calls the update in which it merges/updates the updates. Now I know there's probably a bunch of things worrying about my code, but I am just experimenting with Hibernate and all is working like I want it to, up until now. When I execute this code, I get this error:

```
2023-09-28T04:27:34.004+02:00 ERROR 23584 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.R.P.DataAccess.LifterAccess.LifterDao  : No row with the given identifier exists: [Entities.LifterRecord#com.Romero.PRDataBased.Entities.PersonalRecord_LifterID@2685fdd9]
```

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void update(Lifter lifter) {
    try{
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.merge(lifter);
        session.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
}

@Override
public Optional<Lifter> get(Long id) {
    try{
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Lifter lifter = session.get(Lifter.class, id);
        session.close();
        return Optional.of(lifter);
    }catch(Exception e ){
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

public void addRecordToLifter(AddRecord addRecord){
    Lifter lifter = get(addRecord.getLifterId()).get();
    LifterRecord lifterRecord = new LifterRecord(lifter, addRecord.getPersonalRecord());
    lifter.getLifterRecords().add(lifterRecord);
    update(lifter);
}
```

And I do not understand it! I am trying to *add* a new value (a new personal record + entries in the junction table). Why is it then failing because it can't find the **new** composite key?

And more importantly, what can I try to fix this? I've been at this up until 4 AM local time, so I decided to give up and ask around. I first tried to use session.update, but then the query wouldn't even execute, for reasons unknown to me.

My database design:

[image]

Comment: May I ask what tool you use to generate the table relationship diagram?

Comment: @时间只会一直走 it’s built in pgAdmin